# Elmah for .NET Core - manually logging

Tags: asp.net-core, elmah

I've got an app that has elmah embedded in it for error logging.  That app runs .net framework 4.x and uses a sql server backend.  It is hosted up in azure.

I am porting the app the .net core and to connect to the same database and I need to store more information than just errors.

How does one manually enter an error into elmah under asp .net core?

Comment: What do you mean about manually enter an error into elmah? You want a form somewhere where you can insert errors manually, or?

Comment: I am trying to find a method that looks something like this:
Elmah.EntryWrite(errorInfo) and that method then stores the information in the tables that make up elmah.  I'm doing this in .NET core, not .net, and have not been able to find anything.  If there is something, please let me know.

Comment: Which ELMAH NuGet package did you install in your .NET Core project?

Comment: I installed ElmahCore https://www.nuget.org/packages/ElmahCore/1.2.5/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `HttpContext.RiseError(new InvalidOperationException("Test"));` as mentioned in the https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore/#rise-exception ?

Answer (score 0):

The silver bullet here is
`ElmahExtensions.RaiseError(exception);` ([Reference](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore/issues/50#issuecomment-1233983917))